# bind9 upgrade on Linux lenny distribution

Tags: linux, security, debian-lenny

I have to update my bind9 package in my Debian lenny server. Please suggest me what is the best way to do this. This server does not have internet connection. And this operation should not affect the exist system setup. Can any one  please suggest me on this.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't re-ask it, instead wait for the moderators to move it over for you. You can also flag your own question to ask for a move, I believe.

Comment: @derobert, true enough -- or wait for "the community" to move it. (It's got four votes right now, the fifth vote ought to move it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For disconnected machines, the `apt-offline` tool promises to make installing packages tolerable:

```
Description: offline apt package manager
 apt-offline is an Offline APT Package Manager
 .
 apt-offline can fully update and upgrade an APT based distribution without
 connecting to the network, all of it transparent to apt
 .
 apt-offline can be used to generate a signature on a machine (with no network).
 This signature contains all download information required for the apt database
 system. This signature file can be used on another machine connected to the
 internet (which need not be a Debian box and can even be running windows) to
 download the updates.
 The downloaded data will contain all updates in a format understood by apt and
 this data can be used by apt-offline to update the non-networked machine.
 .
 apt-offline can also fetch bug reports and make them available offline
```

You could look into the [Debian backports](http://backports-master.debian.org/) repositories to bring newer software to older distributions. It might not be transparent to the rest of the system, but hopefully *better* than relying on compiling from source.

Comment: FYI, Lenny is currently oldstable and still has security support. Including the recent bind9 DSA.

Comment: Sweet; that saves the hassle of backports. I never really got the hang of the Debian names (I always just ran `unstable` on my workstations, until I popped over to Ubuntu -- where the names make even less sense).

Comment: http://www.debian.org/releases/ may help some, as might http://www.debian.org/security/ So does the actual bind9 DSA at http://www.debian.org/security/2011/dsa-2347

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need bind9 if your Server is offline? Make it online and:

```
# sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade bind9
```

Or download latest bind9 packages on online machine:

```
# apt-get -d install bind9
```

It should be stored here:

```
# ls -l /var/cache/apt/archives/bind9*
```

Copy files to your offline Server and execute:

```
 # apt-get install bind9
```

Something like that...

Comment: Well, the obvious answer is that the server is connected to a network, maybe even an internet, but not the Internet. (Having name resolution on your internal networks is quite useful, even on networks which aren't connected to the Internet for security or cost reasons)

Comment: You'd also need the `Releases` files and so forth. If you're not using something like `apt-offline` but moving packages by hand, you might as well stick with `dpkg -i` on the target machine.